# Randomly pull more than one line from text file in PHP

Tags: php, text-files

So currently I have a textfile called 'flatfile.txt' that has roughly fifty different lines, all websites; e.g http://facebook.com or something similar. What I'm wanting to happen is have PHP open the textfile, pull a line out, and then do it again, roughly 30 times.

```
<?php
$one = $url;
$httprefix = array("http://", "https://");
$trunclink1 = str_replace($httprefix, '', $one);
?>
<div class="view link">
   <img src="http://immediatenet.com/t/l?Size=1024x768&amp;URL=<? echo $one;?>" height="200px" width="300px" />
   <div class="mask">
        <h2><? echo $trunclink1;?></h2>
        <p><? echo $description; ?></p>
        <a href="#" class="info">Read Comments</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

So $url is the output of what PHP takes out of the textfile, and so when I get to $two, I want $url to give another random line, perhaps http://twitter.com
I'm quite new to PHP, so I may have some newbie mistakes in there, but any help would be awesome. I think it is a foreach loop that is needed, but not sure.

Comment: You want the lines to be in random order?  Can you repeat previously used lines?

Comment: More like, PHP goes into the file pulls a random line out, shoves it into the $url variable, and next time its called in a similar situation, PHP goes back into the textfile and randomly selects another and the process is redone about 30 times. Also, yeah, no repeats :D

Comment: What you propose isn't enough.  You either need to read the whole file into an array of lines (memory intensive for large files), or figure out how many lines are in the file ahead of time, and the offsets for each line (requires a second pass).  The reason for this is that you cannot have repeats, so your application must have a way of keeping track of what is available.

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose since this is just a school project for a media studies class, not a live site, I could load the whole file into an array with '$lines = file('mainbase.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);' then shuffle it, then use array_rand. How intenisve does that get? The file wont be big anyway.

Comment: That's exactly what I would suggest for smaller files.  If you have 1,000 lines or less, go for it.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
foreach (array_rand(file('flatfile.txt'), 30) as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```